# If condition understanding problem in c with syntax

Tags: c

```
if (!(c & ~0xFF))
    c |= 0x0700;
```

Here what not than do what.
Not able to understand this statement

[Sorry but my mind was just gone blur after writing too much code that i was not able to understand so a simple thing sorry for wasting your all times]
Sorry once again

Comment: What *specifically* don't you understand?

Comment: Here if is comparing what

Comment: Do you understand what the operators `!`, `&`. and `~` do?

Comment: Just means if `c <= 255` then `c += 1,792`; bit-flags to indicate some stuffs.

Comment: Yes ofcourse i understand operators

Comment: So I'll ask again: what it is you don't understand?

Comment: *Here if is comparing what* You seem to believe that an `if` condition needs to be a comparison. That is not true. Any boolean expression will do. This can be the result of a comparison, a boolean variable or any other expression. If there is another value than a boolean expression given, it is converted to bool. For this purpose, any value that is not 0 is considered `true`.

Comment: @SparKot: No, it does not. If `c` is an `int` with value −1 and the common two’s complement representation, then `c <= 255` is true but `!(c & ~0xFF)` is false.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of the code is:

- If `c`, widened to at least an `int`, has no bits above the first eight set, turn attempt to turn on the three bits that are on in `0x0700` (bits 8, 9, and 10).

Equivalently:

- If `0 <= c && c < 256`, turn attempt to on the three bits that are on in `0x0700`.

For simplicity, we assume an ordinary C implementation using two’s complement and a `char` narrower than an `int`. Then, in detail:

- `0xFF` has value 255. In its binary representation, the low eight bits are on, and all higher bits are off. The type of this constant is `int`.
- `~0xFF` inverts each bit. The low eight bits are off, and all higher bits are on.
- `c & ~0xFF` performs a bitwise AND, but first, if `c` is narrower than an `int`, it converts `c` to an `int`. (Technically this depends on the ranks of the types, but “narrower” suffices in ordinary C implementations.) This conversion is important because it may act to extend the sign bit of `c`, discussed below. If `c` is an  `unsigned int` or is wider than an `int`, then `~0xFF` is converted to a wider type. Because `~0xFF` is a negative value and two’s complement is used, the result of this conversion still has all of its high bits set.
- In the result of the bitwise AND, the low eight bits are off, and the only high bits set are those that were set in `c` (after conversion, if performed).
- `!(c & ~0xFF)` tests this result. It is true if and only its operand is zero, meaning no bits are set in `c & ~0xFF`.

If `c` is negative, then, after conversion to an `int` if necessary, it will have its sign bit set, so there will be a bit above the first eight set, so the test will be false. Otherwise, any conversion to an `int` will not turn on any bits, so the test will be true if and only if `c` has no bits above the first eight set. Therefore, the test is equivalent to “`c` is greater than or equal to 0 and is less than 256.”

`c |= 0x0700` performs a bitwise OR of `c` with `0x0700` and stores the result in `c`.  If `c` is wide enough, the bits that are on in `0x0700` will be turned on in `c`. If `c` is not wide enough but is unsigned, the bits that do not fit will be ignored. If `c` is not wide enough but is signed, an implementation-defined conversion will be performed (or a signal will be raised), and the result could be anything.

So, what this code does is, if `0 <= c && c < 256`, turn on the bits that are on in `0x0700`, subject to the exceptional conditions described above.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>    if (!(c & ~0xFF)) c |= 0x0700;
> ```

`~0xFF` is the same as `0xF...FFFFF00` or all bits `1` except the 8 least-significant ones.

`(c & 0xF...FFFFF00)` is the most significant bits of `c` followed by 8 `0` bits

`!(c & 0xFFFFFF00)` is either `0` (false) or `1` (true). It's *false* if the thing inside the parenthesis is not zero, *true* otherwise.

So, the full expression sets bits 8, 9, and 10 of `c` if the first most-significant bits of the initial `c` were all `0` (same as `if ((c / 256) == 0)` or `if ((c >> 8) == 0)`).

Comment: The condition is true if all bits excepts the 8 least significant are *clear*, so it's the same as `c < 256`.

Comment: @dbush: No, it is not. If `c` is an int with value −1 and the common two’s complement representation, then `c < 256` is true but `!(c & ~0xFF)` is false.

Comment: Re “if the 8 least-significant bits of the initial `c` were all `0`”: The low eight bits of `c` are irrelevant to the result as they are masked out.

Comment: Re “if the first most-significant bits of the initial `c`”: Almost. If `c` is an eight-bit `signed char`, it has no more significant bits than its low eight bits, yet `!(c & ~0xFF)` will be true.

Comment: @pmg: That is true if `c` is unsigned. But we are considering the case where it is signed. Then `c | 0x0700` is not representable in the type of `c`, so an implementation-defined conversion is performed.